# What natural animal could represent a goddess of Chaos and Entropy

Tags: magic, medieval, gods

I am looking for this in a context of extending a role play universe for my player. The animal should be cute enough though since it is not an evil goddess, and the goddess use to be an oriental (read a Japan like) country.

I am really short on ideas though so I ask you all.

---

To make the question more reusable, I suggest to categorize the gods of chaos animals. Themes could be mind based chaos (panic, riots, mental illness), chaotic trickery and behaviour, physical chaos (entropy, quantum based chaos).

Furthermore, we can categorize using their alignment: how good/bad the said god is.

Comment: Unfortunately there's no way for us to judge any answer as being better than another. As such any correct answer could only be considered to be primarily opinion based.

Comment: First define what you mean by chaos, because there are several means that relate to different things. Answers below take what you mean as what is called a Psychopomp, ie a Trixster god, like Loki, one mentions a "War god"... which is a bad go to cuz Egyptian mythology all gods were against Chaos. Apophus wasn't a god. This is Void chaos (the state before the universe). Bastet I guess could be considered a chaos god if you take it as destruction, but then there are gods of Luck (I think Odin) which is another form of Chaos. Determine this then build out from it.

Comment: Squirrels!  After all, they are the greatest cyber-terrorists on the planet.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I  would go for an animal associated with trickery and cunning, simply because that is, in a sense, the very nature of chaos.

Wikipedia lists some [tricksters in lore](https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/List_of_fictional_tricksters), mainly non animals, but a few real animals associated with trickery too. There is also the following passage on the wiki-page

> Hynes and Doty, in Mythical Trickster Figures (1997) state that every trickster has several of the following six traits:[1]
>
> - fundamentally ambiguous and anomalous
> - deceiver and trick-player
> - shape-shifter
> - situation-inverter
> - messenger and imitator of the gods
> - sacred and lewd bricoleur

These aspects are often highly associated with chaos and entropy.

**So, which animal to choose, then?**
*Fox!* A fox is cute and in most cultures associated with trickery and cunning (I guess everyone knows the saying "as cunning as a fox"). It would be a great image of such goddess.

There are ample of famous trickster foxes:

- [Kitsune](https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/Kitsune), the Japanese trickster fox.
- [Reynard](https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/Reynard), famous in several European countries.
- [Kuma Lisa](https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/Kuma_Lisa) from Bulgaria and Russia.

If you don't want a fox, then there are some other animals also associated with trickery:

- [Coyote](https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/Coyote_(mythology)), "the native American version of the fox".
- [Anansi](https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/Anansi), an African spider.
- [Puss in boots](https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/Puss_in_Boots), even cats can be cunning.
- [Raven](https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cultural_depictions_of_ravens), while not really associated with trickery, ravens are often associated with omens, knowledge and death, which fits to the chaos part.

Answer (score 1):

might I recommend something naturally destructive like a woodpecker or locusts? There are plenty of unlucky birds too.
also I don't think "oriental" is pc anymore.
perhaps a cuckoo or a mimicing lyrebird would suit the personality of your god.

Answer (score 1):

The egyptian goddess [Bastet](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Bastet) was originally the goddess of war. This might fit well into the category of "chaos". At the same time she was the protector of lower egypt. This fits into the requirement of "not evil".

Bastet was depicted as a lioness-warrior and later changed into a cat-goddess.

Therefore a cat or lioness could be a good representation for your good goddess of Chaos.

Answer (score 1):

My suggestion would be a fox, as this would call back to the Japanese [Kitsune](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Kitsune). In folk tales, the kitsune is often portrayed as a trickster spirit that spreads mischief, which would fall in line with the idea of 'chaos' quite well.

Answer (score 1):

I suggest a Yorkshire Terrier. It's undeniably cute and has, pound for pound, an unmatched ability to create chaos :)

Comment: Oh my god, never thought about these little almost explosive dogs, Jack Russell terrier could also be a nice possibility

Comment: Brilliant, that made my day :)