# What would be a good animal to represent chaos?

Tags: gods

I have a world of six gods currently: Chaos, Tranquility, Love, Hate, Regrowth, Rot

Each of these gods has a corresponding animal I’m basing their design on, and every god has been relatively pain free to design.

Except chaos, nothing seems to fit him well.

To really expand on this, I’m looking to represent chaos as an incredibly impartial and unbiased god, aloof, almost naive but also still quite spontaneous. I’m also looking to avoid the current categories of animals already used:

Tranquility - rabbit
Love - swan
Hate - snake
Regrowth - sheep
Rot - hyena

Of course, for the other gods if you have better suggestions please make them. The only one I’m really set on is love and hate. But I’m mainly looking for a good animal counterpart for chaos.

Comment: Welcome to worldbuilding. Please take a moment to visit the [help] and familiarize yourself with our site policy. Unfortunately this question isn't a good fit for this site. While it's definitely about worldbuilding, we prohibit questions that are too subjective. If a question has too many valid answers it's not a good fit. There's no reason why any animal couldn't represent chaos in your world, which means that besides your personal preferences there isn't any way to answer the question objectively.

Comment: Agree with @sphennings, I find the VTC on the basis of it being Opinion Based to be problematic. However, this as worded is a clear example of such. If however you were to ask "What animals are classically associated with chaos?". You may get closer to squeaking by the filter. Im sure that is debatable though.  Having said all that. My answer is Cat or Platypus :)

Comment: Duplicate of [What natural animal could represent a goddess of Chaos and Entropy](https://worldbuilding.stackexchange.com/q/68716/32451)

Comment: All of my pet rabbits were Lords of Chaos (and quite destructive). Like cats, they were affectionate only when they wanted to be.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [What natural animal could represent a goddess of Chaos and Entropy](https://worldbuilding.stackexchange.com/questions/68716/what-natural-animal-could-represent-a-goddess-of-chaos-and-entropy)

Comment: Pure opinion is what you're soliciting here and as a result your question has been closed, when you have time you should perhaps take [the tour](https://worldbuilding.stackexchange.com/tour) 

Comment: I agree with the VTC. I apologize, Anon, but our [help/dont-ask] clearly states, "To prevent your question from being flagged and possibly removed, avoid asking subjective questions where every answer is equally valid." and the [help/on-topic] again states, "If you are looking for discussion, brainstorming, or an overall process rather than specific questions and answers, the Worldbuilding Stack Exchange might not be a good place for your question." Every animal on Earth could be rationally listed with justifying reasons - and no one is better than any other, it's just brainstorming.

Answer (score 2):

The platypus.  It's a mammal, with a duck's bill and feat... it lays eggs... it's venous but only the males and the poison isn't from a bite but a claw on it's rear foot... and the mothers don't suckle their young, but sweat out the milk which the... pups... what is a baby platypus called... lap up from their mothers fur.  They are also blind underwater, but can detect electricity, and their sex is determined by 10 separate chromosome pairs.  They were believed to be a prank by scientists when described and even on seeing one stuffed and brought back to Europe initially, and are universally considered to be the best argument for Creationism, because only some sort of intelligence with too many left over parts lying around could kitbash this thing into existence.  And despite it's common name being Platypus, it is not a member of the Genus Platypus because that Genus was used to describe several species of beatles, so they decided that it's scientific name should be **Ornithorhynchus anatinus** which literally means "Duck-like Bird Snout" after the term was discovered to have been used first after it's brief and better summerizing former scientific Nomenclature of **Ornithorhynchus paradoxus** which translates roughly to "By all logic should not be possible bird-snout thing".

And with almost having a scientific name like that, how can you not take the Platypus as your God of Chaos.  Tremble before his mighty form before he smites you with a waffle!

Comment: Sorry but it's already taken, widely known to be the totem animal of Perplexidia goddess of confusion 

Answer (score 1):

If it can truly be any animal, my vote would be a naked human.

Build up the lore that it's a mystery to humans what animal represents chaos since they disdain it, the other God's never talk about it, and any statue or drawing of the animal is always destroyed beyond recognition.  Maybe Chaos picked their animal last to the rage of all the other Gods, since the animals naturally take on their personas in the world.

Answer (score 0):

How about you create a unique animal? There are plenty of mythological animals to choose from--dragon, basilisk, or kitsune, to name a few.

Or, you could have the god of chaos be the only god to be represented by several animals, and at any given moment may align more with one animal than another. You wouldn't need to pick a particularly chaotic list of animals for this idea, as switching between symbols would be chaotic enough.

If you don't like either of these ideas, you can always pick something like a cat, an animal that possesses an enormous personality. Something like that would be unpredictable (spontaneous) but would not necessarily be fixated symbolically to good or bad.